# How to count duplicate entries in a vector?

Tags: r, vector, grouping

I have a vector like this:

```
v = c('Max', 'Max', 'Sven', 'Bob')
```

How can I count the occurances for all items? The result should contain unique labels, each with its number of occurances. In the example, this could look like this:

```
> result
$Max
[1] 2

$Sven
[1] 1

$Bob
[1] 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `table(v)`? Or maybe `as.list(table(v))` to be closer to what you posted as expected output. If you want it ordered descending you can do `as.list(sort(table(v), decreasing = T))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
table(v)
```

or, if the desired output format is a list, use:

```
as.list(table(v))
```

*Thanks @AntoniosK for providing this answer in a comment*